# finding number of values returned by numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to find the number of places where numpy.where has evaluated as true. The following solution works, but is pretty ugly.

```
b = np.where(a < 5)
num = (b[0]).shape[0]
```

I'm coming from a language where I need to check if num > 0 before proceeding to do something with the resulting array. Is there a more elegant way of getting num, or a more Pythonic solution than finding num?

(For those familiar with IDL, I'm trying to replicate its simple `b = where(a lt 5, num)`.)

Comment: If you like it better you can also do `len(b[0])`

Answer (score 6):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.arange(10)

In [3]: np.count_nonzero(arr < 5)
Out[3]: 5
```

or

```
In [4]: np.sum(arr < 5)
Out[4]: 5
```

---

If you have to define `b = np.where(arr < 5)[0]` anyway, use `len(b)` or `b.size` ( `len()` seems to be a tiny bit faster, but they are pretty much the same in terms of performance).

Comment: OK, thanks. I should clarify that I need the index array from where anyway, I just also need num. Given that, the solution that I came up with is presumably marginally faster than yours, and both take up an extra line of code over what I'm used to.

But I have also discovered that I don't really need to check num most of the time. Performing an operation indexing with an empty array is allowed by Python (and does nothing). Which is simultaneously awesome and weird.

Comment: @user2162806 -- if you already have `b = np.where(arr < 5)[0]` you can just do `len(b)` or `b.size` (`len` seems to be a tiny bit faster, but they are pretty much the same in terms of performance)

Answer (score 0):

This only works if the condition of the where statement implies that the result is not evaluated to False. But then it's easy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(1,11,100)
a_5 = a[np.where(a>5)]
a_10 = a[np.where(a>10)]
a_5.any() #True
a_10.any() #False
```

So if you wish you can try this before assigning, of course:

```
a[np.where(a>5)].any() #True
a[np.where(a>10)].any() #False
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
In [14]: a = np.arange(100)
In [15]: np.where(a > 1000)[0].size > 0
Out[15]: False
In [16]: np.where(a > 10)[0].size > 0
Out[16]: True
```

Comment: Ah, I like size better than shape (no need to [0] it). Thanks.